# attribute name get value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, append, attr

I have this code html:

```html
<select id='id_select'>
 <option name='nm_opt' value='23'>Val1</option>
 <option name='nm_opt2' value='16'>Val2</option>
 <option name='nm_opt' value='6'>Val3</option>
</select>
```

How can I take the value of the name attribute with jQuery?
I tried the following code but did not return anything:

```js
val_id_template = $('#id_select').append().attr("name");
console.log(val_id_template);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `append()` and try. It will give you the `name` value of the selected `option` in the `select` list when you use `$('#id_select option:selected')`:

```js
val_id_template = $('#id_select option:selected').attr("name");
console.log(val_id_template);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='id_select'>
 <option name='nm_opt' value='23'>Val1</option>
 <option name='nm_opt2' value='16'>Val2</option>
 <option name='nm_opt' value='6'>Val3</option>
</select>
```

Or if you want to get the value of `name` on selecting the `option` from the list then:

```js
$('#id_select').change(function(){
  console.log($('#id_select option:selected').attr('name'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='id_select'>
 <option name='nm_opt' value='23'>Val1</option>
 <option name='nm_opt2' value='16'>Val2</option>
 <option name='nm_opt' value='6'>Val3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `$('#id_select option:selected')`

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Can you help me with just javascript (no jquery)?